# How to view truncated inline style CSS blocks in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to track down the source of some bad styling in the browser, but when I click through to the source of it from the Styles pane, I'm taken to one of many inline `<style>` blocks that are automatically generated on the page, which after a certain point, is truncated with `…`, as seen below. If I try to "Edit as HTML" or other methods to copy the block's contents, it doesn't expand this. Is there any way to see the full source of it?

[image: Chrome Dev Tools screenshot of Elements pane where CSS is truncated with "…"]

Comment: For stylesheets generated via insertRule API there'll be no HTML text. You can see the rules using "Properties" subpanel in the inspector: expand the style's properties, `sheet`, `cssRules`. It's inconvenient though so I'd just run this in the console: [...document.styleSheets].map(s=>{let text;try{text=[...s.cssRules].map(r=>r.cssText).join('\n')}catch(e){}return{node:s.ownerNode,text}})

Answer (score -3):

Firefox can get the full style text.